# Python read text file, split into blocks and write to csv

Tags: python, csv, text

I am trying to change this text file into a CSV file that I can then analyse in Pandas
The file being read is Network health data, and maintains the following format in 10 line blocks.
Only lines 1, 5 & 6 are useful data in each block

I can open the file as a file object and access a line at a time
but how do I format it for a CSV and how do I skip lines, rather than writing empty lines to a CSV file

Line 1 - Date & Time
3 lines that are not important
Line 5 - contains 3 pieces of data (transmitted / received / loss)
Line 6 - min / avg / max / stddev
4 Empty lines ..

### Tue  3 Nov 2020 13:09:47 GMT

60 packets transmitted, 60 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.837/28.588/161.246/25.232 ms

### Tue  3 Nov 2020 13:10:47 GMT

60 packets transmitted, 60 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.750/25.999/126.457/20.212 ms

Comment: Each text file contains 10 lines? How many files do you have to process?

Comment: Thanks - I figured it out !